# Glitched page redirects to image

Tags: images, urls

I find that now the **/contact** page shows an image with name contact.jpg instead of the page with that contact slug.

https://foo.com/contact redirects to https://foo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/contact.jpg instead of the page **/contact**

Renaming the image to something like **contact-img.jpg** does not fix the link. It keeps redirecting to a 404 image regardless of the existing page with that name.

Had to make the contact page slug as **/contact-us** meanwhile

Comment: I'm not sure the correct way to edit an image's slug, but you can probably just edit it directly in the database in the wp-posts table.

Comment: Yeah, it solved the issue, thanks @Rup If you want to write a short answer, so I can Validate it, go ahead :)